# database doesn't show using GET method

Tags: php, mysqli

I need help.i have this database

```
student_code: 1234

student_id: angel

namaFoto: angel.jpg
```

using `GET method` to call specific data from database, i use this code below, but the data doesn't show up. what did i do wrong?

```html
<?php
include_once "library/inc.sesadmin.php";
$row = 25;
$hal  = isset($_GET['hal']) ? $_GET['hal'] : 1;

if($usertype != 'Admission'||$usertype != 'Administrator'){
    
if($_GET) {
 $Kode = $_GET['Kode'];
 $myQry=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM student WHERE student_code='$Kode'");
 $myQry->execute();
    $myQryCount = $myQry->rowCount();

 while ($myData = $myQry->fetch()) {
 }
}

?>
<table >
        <tr>
      <td ><img src="foto/<?php echo $namaFoto; ?>"></td>
      <td ><b>Code</b></td>
      <td ><b>:</b></td>
      <td ><?php echo $myData['student_code']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Student ID </b></td>
      <td><b>:</b></td>
      <td> <?php echo $myData['student_id']; ?>  </td>
    </tr>
</table>
      <?php } else { ?>
      <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />
      <p align="center">You are not authorized to access this area</p>
      <?php } ?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because user data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.

Comment: Does the get variable come from html form or URL?  Also check if it's empty

Comment: You might have a SQL error, or you might not be running the query you think you are.

Comment: href="?open=Student-Print-Adm&amp;Kode='.$row['student_code'‌​].'"   how can i make it save from SQL injection? could you please give me example?

Answer (score 0):

Are you including ?Kode=1234 on the URL you are using to access the page? Also the image isn't using the same $myData collection to retrieve the image value. That may not be a root-cause issue, but does look to be a big.

Comment: yes, i use href="?open=Student-Print-Adm&amp;Kode='.$row['student_code'].'" to call the page.how can i call the image then?

Comment: Are you sure the number is being passed for Kode? What's the URL look like when you click on the link? It seems the number isn't being passed.